# How to configure the Racket interpreter to support command history?

Tags: racket, readline, input-history

I've just set up Racket and have been trying out the interpreter.

However, I can't seem to go up and down the command history using the arrows (or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for that matter) or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to search through it.

Is that even supported? Can I build it with that feature in?

Coming from a Python background I'm very used to these features and would like to have them available for Racket too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## DrRacket IDE

In the Racket IDE you can hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with arrow keys to get to previously written statements in the interactions window.

## Racket in terminal

**eXtended REPL**

Extended REPL gives read-line features like using arrows to go back in history as well as you can search with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. It has in addition REPL-commands like `,apropos`. By entering `,help` you get a list of commands you can use or you can consult the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/). To use it you can:

1. enter `(require xrepl)` to activate it
2. run racket with `racket -il xrepl`
3. install it once and for all from xrepl by evaluating `,install!`

**Standard readline**

You have [normal readline](http://docs.racket-lang.org/readline/) which you can activate by:

1. enter `(require readline/rep)` to activate it
2. run racket with `racket -il readline`
3. install in once and for all by evaluating `(install-readline!)`.

Comment: Hmm, I get `; Warning: no readline support (ffi-lib: couldn't open "libreadline.so.5" (/usr/lib64/libreadline.so.5: undefined symbol: PC))` so I guess it can't be helped in my case, but it looks like all of the above does work. Thanks!

Comment: @Nobilis Try starting racket with `env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libcurses.so racket`. (It's a hint from [this page](https://lotabout.github.io/orgwiki/racket_notes.html), but I have no idea if it will work)

Comment: @Nobilis If you can't get readline to work, try a pre-release version from download.racket-lang.org. The pre-release version has a fallback version of "readline" (where "" means I can't remember what the fallback is).

Comment: @Sylwester Cool, that seemed to work, thanks very much!

Comment: I can't make the `ctrl + r` work with my racket REPL. Does anyone run into the same thing as me?

Comment: @yanyingwang It might be that your terminal or OS is overriding CTRL + r for some other purpose. Eg. I have the same issue in iTerm on MacOS, but I'm not using that combination so much as to have investigated why that is.

Comment: @Sylwester yes you are right. I've tried that and it turns out the `ctrl+r` works very well on my ubuntu virtual machine, but I just can not make it work on my macOS no matter with iTerm or macOS's default terminal. Does anyone have a successful working experience of it on the macOS?